# Skip blank lines with Parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

New to Parsec, a beginner's question. How can one parse a file of lines where some lines may be blank, consisting only of whitespace followed by a newline? I just want to skip them, not have them in the parsed output.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

-- alias for parseTest
run :: Show a => Parser a -> String -> IO ()
run = parseTest

-- parse lines
p :: Parser [[String]]
p = lineP `endBy` newline <* eof
  where lineP = wordP `sepBy` (char ' ')
        wordP = many $ noneOf "\n"
```

Example parse with blank line:

```
*Main> run p "z x c\n1 2 3\n    \na\n"
[["z x c"],["1 2 3"],["    "],["a"]]
```

I suspect I am going about this all wrong.

Comment: Why not just `filter (any (not . isSpace)) . lines`?

Comment: I have abstracted out the details of what I am doing for the purpose of simplifying the question. I am parsing a configuration file, not just into words, but into keys and values of various complex sorts. It seems to me that the parser should be able to discard blank lines as part of its grammar, and that one should not do this at the lexical read of the file level.

Comment: Your `wordP` parses spaces, so the `\`sepBy\` (char ' ')` does not really do anything.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `newline`, you could define a custom parser that captures *your* notion of the end of a line, which would parse at least one `newline`, and then optionally many empty lines (i.e. whitespaces followed by another newline). You will need the `try` operator to backtrack if the whitespace is not followed by another newline (or the end of input, I guess):

Code:

```
-- parse lines
p :: Parser [[String]]
p = lineP `endBy` lineEnd <* eof
  where lineP = wordP `sepBy` (char ' ')
        wordP = many $ noneOf " \n"

lineEnd :: Parser ()
lineEnd = do
    newline
    many (try (many (oneOf " \t") >> newline))
    return ()
```

Output:

```
*Main> run p "z x c\n1 2 3\n    \na\n"
[["z","x","c"],["1","2","3"],["a"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach might be to think of a file as a series of lines that are either blank or non-blank. The following expresses this idea with the expression `line <|> emptyLine`. The following uses the `Maybe` datatype to distinguish between the result of parsing a non-blank line, using `catMaybes` to filter out the `Nothing`s at the end.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver lts-7.0
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package parsec
-}

import Prelude hiding (lines)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

-- parse lines
p :: Parser [[String]]
p = catMaybes <$> lines
  where lines = (line <|> emptyLine) `endBy` newline <* eof
        line = Just <$> word `sepBy1` spaces1
        emptyLine = spaces1 >> pure Nothing
        word = many1 $ noneOf ['\n', ' ']
        spaces1 = skipMany1 (char ' ')

main = parseTest p "z x c\n1 2 3\n    \na\n"
```

Output is:

```
[["z","x","c"],["1","2","3"],["a"]]
```

Another approach might be to use `Prelude` functions along with `Data.Char.isSpace` to collect the non-blank lines before you get started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver lts-7.0
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package parsec
-}

import Data.Char
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

p :: Parser [[String]]
p = line `endBy` newline <* eof where
  line = word `sepBy1` spaces1
  word = many1 $ noneOf ['\n', ' ']
  spaces1 = skipMany1 (char ' ')

main = parseTest p (unlines nonBlankLines)
  where input = "z x c\n1 2 3\n    \na\n"
        nonBlankLines = filter (not . all isSpace) $ lines input
```

Output is:

```
[["z","x","c"],["1","2","3"],["a"]]
```

This is pretty simple and has the additional benefit that using `lines` will not require a `newline` at the end of each line (this helps with portability).

Note, there was a small bug with your `wordP` parser. Also note that, as specified, these parsers do not cope with preceding or trailing spaces (on non-blank lines). I'm imaging that your non-minimal code is more resilient.